# how to accept http control request headers in python

Tags: python-3.x, flask, godot

i'm creating an api for a video game in python, but i ran into a problem: when i put the videogame on itch.io it can't contact the api. on another forum they advised me to use this code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 8640000'); // cache for 100 days
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
}
```

but i don't know how to integrate it into the API flask code, can someone help me?

Comment: That looks like php to me, not python. You cant use php in flask

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use CORS. Try flask-cors package
https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: oh okok thx, but how can I use it in flask_restful?